# Are the Windows 10 and Windows 7 Command prompt commands identical?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cmd.exe

I know Microsoft likes to add commands to windows cmd as they go along, however, I was wondering if there are any differences in commands for Windows 10 versus Windows 7? I'm referring to commands like those you would use in a batch file, not the actual CMD interface.

Comment: There are some differences in the console behaviour, but (AFAIK) there are no differences in the underlying commands. See [Windows 10 Command Prompt: New Console vs. Legacy Console | Password Recovery](https://www.top-password.com/blog/windows-10-command-prompt-new-console-vs-legacy-console/)

Comment: May I suggest modifying your question heading - "command prompt" has a specific meaning which does not, I think, match the body of your question - maybe are the commands available via the Windows 7 and Windows 10 command line identical?

Comment: One of the best improvement is you can paste commands directly into the new command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are new features and new capabilities in CMD in Windows 10, and features are being added with the new Feature Updates too.

The thing is command prompt can run ANY executable on your computer, so any difference in the executables on your computer will be a "different command".

So, the only way to get a meaningful answer for you would be to limit ourselves only to those commands inherent to the command interpreter.

If we limit ourselves only to those commands inherent to the command interpreter, I was unable to find a comparison between the two, but here is a Microsoft document listing the commands available in Windows 10 (and Windows 8.1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands

Comment: I know this is not what you meant, but I have TONS of executables that the command prompt will NOT run.  I use VDos for those, however.

Comment: Without specifics we couldn’t say the reason those applications don’t run.  However, Windows has not ran DOS applications natively since Windows XP

Comment: I'd be surprised to find a file that is actually an executable (not requiring a defined runtime environment) that cannot be triggered within command prompt. While there are many applications that don't run IN the command prompt, they can be started from within it.

Comment: Also, commands that work in Windows 7 can be deprecated in windows 10, such as the AT command. Not to mention that Windows 10's command prompt has different default values, such as a huge screen buffer size.

Comment: I'm referring to universal batch code commands more than external exes more taskkill and echo than regedit.